# Как можно трактовать предложение со словом «помимо»?

Tags: пунктуация

Пунктом 19 приложения N 3 приказа N 302н установлено, что в качестве источника информации о наличии на рабочих местах вредных производственных факторов, помимо результатов оценки условий труда, могут использоваться результаты лабораторных исследований и испытаний, полученные в рамках контрольно-надзорной деятельности, производственного лабораторного контроля, а также эксплуатационная, технологическая и иная документация на машины, механизмы, оборудование, сырье и материалы, применяемые работодателем при осуществлении производственной деятельности.

Вопрос: Слово помимо означает что если есть аттестация рабочих мест, то могут использоваться лабораторные исследования или именно в таком виде имеется в виду что можно использовать  источник информации либо аттестацию либо лабораторные иследования

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Значение слова **"помимо"** по Ефремовой:

> Помимо - с род. пад. Употр. со значениями: 1) кроме, за исключением кого-л., чего-л.;
>
> **2) сверх, вдобавок к чему-л.;**
>
> 3) минуя, не принимая во внимание кого-л., что-л.

Употребляется при соединении предложений, второе из которых дополняет первое и представляется более значительным по сравнению с первым; кроме того что.

Значение слова "помимо"по Ожегову:

> Помимо - Кроме N1 за исключением кого-чего-нибудь
>   Помимо Кроме N2,**в добавление к кому-чему-нибудь**
>   Помимо Минуя, без участия кого-нибудь

В данном тексте просматривается второе значение. Значение "либо то,либо другое " с помощью предлога "помимо" выразить нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь выражение со словом "**помимо**" только добавляет новую возможность (можно использовать и такие результаты, а не только известные или те, о которых перед этим говорилось; **можно** не только это, но и другое). Из сказанного **невозможно** заключить, что эта другая возможность может (в разрешительном смысле) *заменить* ранее упомянутую или наоборот, может использоваться *только в дополнение* к ней. Можно только заключить, что она необязательна для использования: другие результаты "**могут**", а не "**должны**". Поэтому вопросы совместного использования "результатов" или использование одного их вида взамен другого нужно отдельно оговаривать, либо можно изменить форму выражения для придания ему нужного смысла (с использованием слов "**вместо**" или "**одновременно с**").